# Cron job isn't writing to log file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron, io-redirection

I have a shell script that writes the date to a log file when executed. When I run the script manually, the correct output gets written to the file. However, this needs to be automated, and when I run as a cron job, nothing is getting written to  the file and I am confused why.

crontab:

```
0 * * * * tomcat /usr/bin/sh /apps/rdsreplication/snap_replication.sh
```

Sample Code:

```
#/bin/bash/

echo ---------------------------------------- >> create_snap.txt
echo Start time:  >> create_snap.txt
date >> create_snap.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What working directory `pwd` does cron run things under?

Comment: 1. Do you actually have a `/usr/bin/sh`? This is an unusual location for a shell. 2. Which `crontab` file are you using, or how are you adding this line to `cron`? 3. What gets reported in `cron`'s log file (typically somewhere in `/var/log`) for this job?

Comment: @thrig, this is the crontab for the tomcat user, so I assume it is running out of /home/tomcat/.

Comment: @thrig it's the user account's home directory

Comment: @roaima yes, on this server I ran `which sh`, and that was the path returned. I am using the tomcat user's crontab, I am adding the line using `crontab -e`. `/var/log/cron` shows this: `Mar  1 18:06:01 sonar CROND[1585]: (tomcat) CMD (/usr/bin/sh /apps/rdsreplication/snap_replication.sh)`

Comment: @roaima: many systemd-based distros have `/bin` as a symlink to `/usr/bin` nowadays, since it is no longer possible to have `/usr` on a separate partition anyway.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I was thinking of Solaris (not used it for years, though)

Comment: @roaima maybe. But what directory is that? `NULL` on account of Active Directory doing lord knows what? Flapping between what LDAP is providing and a local account, depending on the whims of `sssd` or such?

Comment: @thrig I don't seem to have any problems with `sssd`. In the configurations I use there's a template definition for users' home directories so it doesn't need to be specified in AD. However, regardless of how a user's home directory is set up, that's where the `cron` instance sits. It's up to the user (or sysadmin) to decide whether or not the directory should be writeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell script needs to use the full path for the log file:

```sh
#/bin/bash/
# assuming you want the txt file in the same directory as the bash script
logfile="$(dirname "$0")/create_snap.txt"
{
    echo ----------------------------------------
    echo Start time:
    date 
} >> "$logfile"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a user `crontab`, the man page for `crontab(5)` describes the fields:

> Each line has five time and date fields, followed  by  a  user name if this is the system crontab file, followed by a command.

So in your case, you'd want this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /apps/rdsreplication/snap_replication.sh
```

You should be aware that `cron` will email you the output and *stderr* from the job (if any), so you probably have quite a lot of emails telling you that `cron` can't find the command `tomcat`. (Or if it can, that `tomcat` doesn't understand the rest of the line.)

Comment: I tried this, but the date is still not getting written to the log file. I am assuming this is because it is running out of `/home/tomcat/` and not `/apps/rdsreplication/` where the log file resides? I think if I add this line to the script it should work: `cd /apps/rdsreplication/`.

Comment: @N.M.D I haven't seen your script or your system's setup so I can't comment on good locations to run the script from. The `cron` entry will be run from the user acccount's home directory, so if the script can't run from there it needs to change directory - or you need to use `cd /correct/path && sh /apps/.../snap_replication.sh`.